# Lift state monad to focus on part of a record

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, haskell-lens

With the following code snippet:

```hs
data Circle = Circle 
            { center :: Point
            , radius :: Double
            }

data Point = Point (Double, Double)

someFuncOverPoint :: State Point blahblah
```

I wonder if there is a function that can make the `someFuncOverPoint` to focus on `Circle`:

```
someMagicFunc :: ??? -> State Point blahblah -> State Circle blahblah
```

Maybe this can be implemented using lens?

Comment: @cafce25 `fmap :: (a -> b) -> StateT s m a -> StateT s m b` [does not](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.3.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#v:fmap) change the type of s

Comment: It is quite strange, so you want to change the type of the state variable?

Comment: Another question: what would be the radius here of the `Circle` we are constructing?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I thought we could provide a default value to it(probably 0)...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking you *can*. Indeed, we can create a state by first generating the first `State Point a`, and then pass that into a `State`, so:

```
someMagicFunc :: Double -> State Point a -> State Circle a
someMagicFunc r s = State (\s0 -> let ~(s1, a) = runState s s0 in (Circle s1 r, a))
```

So here we construct a `State` that works with a function that maps the initial state `s0` to the next state `s1` and the result, and then we turn that into a 2-tuple with the `Circle` as state, and the "result" `a` as well.

That being said, it is a bit strange to change the type of the state. Usually the type of the state remains the same over all the actions.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @willeM_VanOnsem's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77415124/8269945).

The motivation here is that I have some hierarchical data structures and some effectful functions that only focus on part of the context, so I need a way to compose them.

I think there's a better way:

```hs
someMagicFunc :: State Point a -> State Circle a
someMagicFunc s = state (\s0 -> let ~(a, s1) = runState s (center s0)
                                in (a, s0 { center = s1 }))
```

And we can reverse the arrow:

```hs
revMagic :: Double -> State Circle a -> State Point a
revMagic r s = state (\s0 -> let ~(a, s1) = runState s (Circle s0 r)
                             in (a, center s1))
```

UPDATE: After some research, I figure out that what I need is in fact [zoom](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.2.3/docs/Control-Lens-Zoom.html#v:zoom) with type `zoom :: Monad m => Lens' s a -> StateT a m r -> StateT s m r`.

Generally, it's trivial if we want to downcast the context in state monad, but if we want to upcast, we may need something like prism to construct the data.